# Scope buttons hide under search bar on iOS 11

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I have a search controller in my app which according to apple documentation on iOS 11 has to be added to the navigationItem's searchController property. I also have some scope buttons for the searchController. Everything works fine but when I rotate my device to landscape and rotate back to portrait then a wired thing happens. The scope buttons gets hidden under the search field. If I press the cancel button and tap on the search field again then it comes back to the normal state. The bug reproduces everytime only on iOS 11. The searchbar will look like this: [image: After rotating back to portrait]

The normal state of the search controller: 
[image: The normal state of the search controller]

This is how I add the searchController:

```
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as UISearchResultsUpdating
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search device"
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Device", "Person", "OS version", "Serial"]

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

        if let textField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            if let backgroundView = textField.subviews.first {
                backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self as UISearchBarDelegate
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is because of the constraints of your segmentedControl (Device, Person, OS Version, Serial)? Do you use layoutMarginsGuide?

Comment: @Y.Bonafons Yes it might be. I'm not using the layoutMarginsGuide.

Comment: Actually I just use the scopeButton property of the searchBar. Like this you don't have access to the segmentedControl's constraints. It sets automatically I think.

Comment: I tested it with iOS 11.0 -> the issue reproduces every time. Also tested with iOS 11.2 and it's not reproducing. So Apple might fixed the issue with an update.

Comment: My bad, I've never used scopeButtonTitles. I confirm that I have the same behavior than you on iOS 11.0 and it's ok on 11.2

Comment: Thank you for trying. I don't know if there is a fix for devices with under iOS 11.2

Comment: did you ever figure out how to fix this? i am having the same issue.

Comment: No, I think it's a bug under iOS 11.2. I can only reproduce it with lower OS versions than that.